# Enable/Disable all buttons under a parent Menu button in Journal Voucher in ax 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I need to disable all the (child)buttons under a menu button(parent).

I need to use this in AccountsPayable->journals->paymentJournal->lines->JournalVoucher, here I want to disable all the child buttons of paymentStatus menu button, Later I'll enable the buttons what I require.

Is there any way, instead of hard coding for all the buttons as button_name.enable(false), In future I may add some more statuses under paymentStatus, so I need to disable all the child buttons without hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the sub controls and disable them. Here a short example of a form's `run` method:

```
public void run()
{
    int i;

    super();
    for (i = 1; i <= menuButton.controlCount(); ++i)
    {
        menuButton.controlNum(i).enabled(false);
    }
}
```